# When deploying Team Project Build from TFSPreview to Azure how to indicate what Web App to deploy?

Tags: azure, deployment, tfs, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I have TFSPreview Account with a Team Project and there is a Build Definition, which builds the solution, in which I have one web application.

I've linked it to Azure to achieve continious deployment (Build Definition uses "AzureContinuousDeployment.11.xaml" workflow).

Everything works fine. What I do not understand, how does it choose which Web App to deploy, if there were several ones? I can't find any settings on this.

upd: i've added second web app project to my solution. the first one is still being deployed. the second one doesn't. I still can find no settings on which of them to deploy.

Comment: same problem with me. google have no answer. did you find anything?

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose the project [when you set up the TFS publishing](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/publishing-with-tfs/#header-2):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer. It was the **Team Project**, that I had successfully choosen during the set up. 

Inside that team project, my solution is stored. It contains **two** web projects. One of _them_ is deployed. Why that one, not another? That is the question.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the build definition file. (go to team explorer and right click on the build being used)
On the Process tab Below where the Template is chosen, Section **1.Required** choose the solution to build